# How to add a string containing HTML with Clojure Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I have defined a template in this way:

```
(deftemplate layout-string "path/to/html/container.html"
  [content-strings]
  [:#container :> :div.pad]  (content (html-snippet (apply str content-strings)))
)
```

Here content-strings contain a HTML (for example: "<tr><td><a href="mylink">my link</a></td></tr>)
Unfortunately this doesn't work. Instead it's removing the <tr> and the <td> leaving only the <a> tag.
I've tried with different approach (with different unsuccessful results).
Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html-content` is the function you need. However it's bad performance-wise. Where does this html string come from?

**EDIT: example**

```
=> (sniptest "<div>"
     [:div] (html-content "<tr><td><a href=\"mylink\">my link</a></td></tr>"))
"<div><tr><td><a href=\"mylink\">my link</a></td></tr></div>"
```

Comment: Unfortunately html-content doesn't work and it looks like it might be a bug of that function since it's producing something like (a href=...">link1</a><a href="...">Link2</a>). I basically produce my HTML using Hiccup, I then stringify it using the hiccup/html function and give it to html-content. It should work very easily (performance aside) but it doesn't :(

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible test case like the above?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! After running your example code (sniptest) I had the brilliant idea to actually check the source HTML generated (I was using the Chrome inspector which displays a modified HTML). I then realized that my HTML was missing the <table> node. Believe it or not I've spent almost 3 days on this :(